# How to print the variable of a class in python

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I am trying to print the variable self.result. The ultimate goal is to use that for further processing, but for now just want to access the variable, so I chose it to print, however I am getting this message:

"wx._controls.StaticText; proxy of Swig Object of type 'wxStaticText *' at 0x23fed48> "

My code is below, any help is appreciated.

```
import wx

class ExampleFrame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
    self.quote = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="is Awesome")
    self.result = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="")
    self.result.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
    self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Save")
    self.lblname = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Your name:")
    self.editname = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, size=(140, -1))

    # Set sizer for the frame, so we can change frame size to match widgets
    self.windowSizer = wx.BoxSizer()
    self.windowSizer.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)

    # Set sizer for the panel content
    self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
    self.sizer.Add(self.quote, (0, 1))
    self.sizer.Add(self.result, (0, 0))
    self.sizer.Add(self.lblname, (1, 0))
    self.sizer.Add(self.editname, (1, 1))
    self.sizer.Add(self.button, (2, 0), (1, 2), flag=wx.EXPAND)

    # Set simple sizer for a nice border
    self.border = wx.BoxSizer()
    self.border.Add(self.sizer, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

    # Use the sizers
    self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.border)
    self.SetSizerAndFit(self.windowSizer)

    # Set event handlers
    self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)

def OnButton(self, e):
    self.result.SetLabel(self.editname.GetValue())



app = wx.App(False)
frame = ExampleFrame(None)
frame.Show()
print frame.result
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: this is not an error you are getting. what you are getting is __repr__() result of variable, which gives you most basic informations about variable: type and address.

Comment: So how do I get the value of the variable? any ideas?

Comment: This is not a variable but an object. Which text would you want to get ?

Comment: whatever I input in the text box. Sorry my programming knowledge is limited and trying to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question makes no sense: Why would you want to read out the label of a static text? Its label (!, `StaticText` has no value) is set by the `OnButton` event, reading the value of the `TextCtrl` named `editname` (I think it is that what you are searching). But to answer your question: How to read a label from a `StaticText` change:

```
print frame.result
```

to

```
print frame.result.GetLabel() # or GetLabelText()
```

This will result in an empty string because the label is not set yet directly after frame creation.

See [documentation parent object of `StaticText`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs.old/html/Control.html#Control.GetLabel).

Comment: Thanks that's helpful. I was not clear while asking the question, sorry. I want to print the label after it is set by the 'onbutton' event. However, as you've pointed out, it returns empty string with the way it is now. Is there a way to return the text entered and not an empty string?

Comment: As I live under the impression you do not have an understanding between cause and effect in your GUI application I will simply answer your question: Put a statement ``print frame.result.GetLabel()`` into the second line of your ``OnButton`` event handler. Start the app. Enter some text. Click the "Save" button (twice). Enjoy. Do not forget to accept my answer. I am out of here.

Comment: May be you are right. Thanks for the tips and I'll mark the question answered, however I did not get what I was looking for as I cant express the question properly. I don't want the print action prompted by the 'save' button. I want to be able to call the object separately, possibly by a second script. I planned to understand how to call it from the same script first and then go for the second script. Anyways, I'll do my own research and figure out. Thanks again